# Rendering a `read_csv()` with markdown hyperlinks and linebreaks into a multi-line/grid table in a quarto website

Tags: knitr, quarto, kable

I have a long and complicated table containing dates and topics of my [course schedule](https://bios-538.github.io/slides/class_schedule.html) page within a quarto website.

I decided to move it into a spreadsheet for flexibly manipulating individual cells. I would like to read and render this spreadsheet in a format similar to quarto's table seen in the above link. Hence I'm trying to render the table as a pipe(or grid) table in an `R` chunk within a `.qmd` quarto website page. I tried these two things -

- `kable(format = "pipe")` works but does not produce a multi-line table since "pipe" format does not support `\n` newline characters(?)
- `pander::pandoc.table(style = "grid") generates a grid_table but it doesn't eventually render as a html and I only see the bare markdown code after the` quarto render .` command on the full website

Here's a small reprex -

````
``` r
options(knitr.kable.NA = "")

# ~~ Load schedule from the spreadsheet
sch <- 
  structure(list(
    
    Lec = c(1, 5), 
    Date = c("09/Jan", "25/Jan"), 
    Topic = c("Introductions and installations", 
              "R basics contd."), 
    Details = c("[slides](lecture01.Rmd) ([PDF](https://bios-538.github.io/))", 
                "for() ; function() and vectorization\n[lec5_demo](scripts/class5_demo_loops-functions.R), [lec5_practice](scripts/class5_practice_loops-functions.R)"
    )), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))

# Render table with "pipe" format: \n (after vectorization) messes it up
knitr::kable(sch, format = 'pipe')
```
````

| Lec | Date | Topic | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09/Jan | Introductions and installations | slides ([PDF](https://bios-538.github.io/)) |
| 5 | 25/Jan | R basics contd. | for() ; function() and vectorization |
| lec5_demo, lec5_practice |  |  |  |

```r
# Render table with pandoc.table "grid"/"rmarkdown" format: Only markdown code shows up, not final .html
pander::pandoc.table(sch, style = 'grid')
#> 
#> 
#> +-----+--------+-------------------+
#> | Lec |  Date  |       Topic       |
#> +=====+========+===================+
#> |  1  | 09/Jan | Introductions and |
#> |     |        |   installations   |
#> +-----+--------+-------------------+
#> |  5  | 25/Jan |  R basics contd.  |
#> +-----+--------+-------------------+
#> 
#> Table: Table continues below
#> 
#>  
#> 
#> +------------------------------------------------------------+
#> |                          Details                           |
#> +============================================================+
#> |                  [slides](lecture01.Rmd)                   |
#> |            ([PDF](https://bios-538.github.io/))            |
#> +------------------------------------------------------------+
#> |                   for() ; function() and                   |
#> |                       vectorization                        |
#> |    [lec5_demo](scripts/class5_demo_loops-functions.R),     |
#> | [lec5_practice](scripts/class5_practice_loops-functions.R) |
#> +------------------------------------------------------------+
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-28 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>